# Web-based System in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Is it okay to develop a company's system in google app engine? The system will just have simple CRUD functionalities and should be used only by customers of the company.

Another option is to have it written in PHP CodeIgniter.

I am more experienced with google-app-engine.

Which one should I go through? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are your concerns?

Comment: Find a way to rationally engage the client and they will tell you what they prefer.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine is great when you can delegate part of the processing to the clients. So It's more designed for web apps - [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application)s (something easily called "Google-like web pages").

PHP, on the other hand, is a server-side script, just like JSP, ASP and so on. So you have different worlds to deal with. My 2 cents: for simple CRUD, use the fastest approach for you to develop it, in this case App Engine with the technology you're used to.

Comment: -1. AppEngine is a hosting system for server-side technologies. And I've no idea what a "Google-like web page" is.

Comment: @DanielRoseman [RIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Internet_application)s, my friend. Try to host server-side only technologies on App Engine to see how painful slow it will be. [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home) and JSP (talking about Java) are examples of that. Pure [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/), on the other hand, is pretty good running on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Have look at the case studies given at this [products](https://cloud.google.com/products/), This could definitely clear your picture in all prospect.